# Can you default Tumblr's Ask feature to ask anonymously

Tags: tumblr, anonymous

I want to default any ask submissions via Tumblr to "Ask Anonymously". How can I do this?

**Clarification**: This is for asks I receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to this. The ask box cannot be edited except for the iFrame. If you are looking to conceal the identity of those who ask from your followers, you can ignore the ask message and ask it again anonymously yourself incognito.